# Caliburn Micro beginning coroutine in constructor - breaking the View?

Tags: c#, silverlight, caliburn.micro

I am using a View Model first approach with CM where I create a ViewModel and activate it immediately after. In the constructor of the ViewModel I am starting a coroutine using the method:

`Coroutine.BeginExecute(Example().GetEnumerator());`

I have a busy indicator in my views, and I set the busy property (that's TwoWay bound to the IsBusy property on the busy indicator control) to true. When true, the indicator shows; when false, it's hidden.

So my coroutine would look something like this:

```
IsBusy = true;
var example = client.AsyncOp();
yield return example;
var exampletwo = client.AnotherAsyncOp();
yield return exampletwo;
IsBusy = false;
```

The issue appears to be IsBusy not propagating to the view correctly. There are occasions when the indicator won't even show. There are other occasions (the most common) where the indicator will show, but won't turn off even after IsBusy is set to false.

I don't believe this is a busy indicator issue as this happens with various other properties. If, for example, I set a property that's bound to a ListBox's SelectedItem, the property will be set, but the ListBox won't show it as its SelectedItem in the GUI.

The Views property has a count of zero when the coroutine is initially executed, and then suddenly has a count of 1 after the first `yield return`. I maybe wrong, but it seems like there's some kind of race condition going on where CM is hooking up the view, and me setting the properties.

I have also tried moving the Coroutine to the OnViewLoaded event, but that still has the same problems, which is curious considering the previous paragraph!

Thanks

Comment: I think the fact that the view not being loaded will definitely be contributing to your issues (however there may be other problems as well). The standard I am using is to have a ViewLoaded co-routine in my VMs which is invoked via an ActionMessage attached to the views loaded event i.e. `<i:Interaction.Triggers><i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded"><cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ViewLoaded" /></i:EventTrigger></i:Interaction.Triggers>` this way the built in co-routine infrastructure is used. Try that and let me know what the result is, also, how is IsBusy property implemented

Comment: @Simon do you add that EventTrigger to the view?  Doesn't CM add that for you?

Comment: @Derek Yes add it to the view. `Screen` in CM provides `OnViewLoaded` but it is not a co-routine (return type of void). Using this approach instead you are a) sure the view has completely loaded and b) are able to use the `ActionMessage` infrastructure for invoking the co-routine (which means the Context param of your co-routines results will be properly instantiated which may be useful in some cases).

Comment: Ah, I see, never thought about that, good idea!

Comment: Unfortunately, Simon, it didn't work. There must be something else preventing it from working. In the end I resolved the problem by loading the data, and then passing it through to the view model's constructor.

Comment: What are the async op's you're trying to do from the coroutine?

Comment: Silly question, is the property for IsBusy notifying when it changes?

Comment: @EtherDragon Yeah, the IsBusy is notifying.

Comment: @Derek The async ops I'm doing are fetching some data from the database and then populating ObservableCollections/BindableCollections with the data.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://baud.cz/blog/coproject-ria-caliburnmicro-demo-part-10) is an excellent example of how to do busy indicator with CM.

Then from your Coroutines you can do:

```
[Import(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public IBusyWatcher Busy { get; set; }

private IEnumerable<IResult> LoadData()
{
    using (Busy.GetTicket())
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The busy indicator itself is fine - the problem is that the bindings aren't propagating through to the view. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've indicated that `client.AsyncOp();` and `client.AnotherAsyncOp();` are async, you've not shown the implementation so it's not clear what's happening in there.

Caliburn.Micro won't make an operation async, you still need to do the work inside your `IResult` so that it is not executed on the UI thread and therefore blocking your BusyIndicator.

There's a really good explanation of coroutines [here](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/03/sequential-asynchronous-workflows-in.html), in particular [this diagram](http://gallery.jeremylikness.com/main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=222&g2_serialNumber=2) which should hopefully make it clearer how your coroutine gets executed by the framework.